# MobileFirst - Modify Java adapters path

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I'd like to modify the Java adapters paths. By default, we have server/appname/adapters/adaptername/....

I'd like to add a value between appname and adapters: server/appname/v1/adapters/adaptername/...

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to modify the adapter path in the requested manner.
Feel free to submit a feature request, here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/help